# Trying to create an HTML brochure that's cross-browser compatible

Tags: html, css, printing

So I have a PDF brochure that we're trying to create a printable HTML version for.
I'm running into a few obstacles including:

- Zoom at 100% vs. Shrink to fit (defaults appear to be different in FF/IE)
- Only printing one page and not having any space after the
  footer (or even just getting "page-break-after:always" to work)
- I have a fluid layout that I'm trying to just use a width: auto on the main wrapper for, but this means not having any kind of width constrictions on the front-end of the HTML page. I don't want to use a min-width or anything.  Was hoping since this is page is strictly for print, I wouldn't have to add a print style sheet (just typing this makes me think I pretty much have to...)
- Should I just use a fixed layout on the HTML page and a fluid layout on the print page?

I may be over thinking this...

Thanks so much for any help.

Comment: Getting specific answers on some of your bullet points will require more details. Screenshots, links, etc.

If you need the web version to look a certain way and the print version to look a certain way, use a print stylesheet -- you will save yourself lots of headaches. Also beware that IE prints differently than a lot of other browsers, so know your audience and TEST TEST TEST!

Comment: Maybe I'm from the future, but do people really print such things? I can't really imagine why you'd want to print a brochure from a webpage. Have you checked customers actually want to do this?

Comment: Agree with Rich Bradshaw, and why not just offer the PDF separately for printing purposes? Also, user preferences will always override your print styles.

Comment: Really appreciate the feedback, it's a real estate property page brochure.  So instead of having it as a PDF, it makes sense to have it as an HTML page so we don't have to re-program and re-do all the PDF's when we make simple data changes.  It was a client request, but it'll help us o our side as well.

Answer (score 2):

I would say make ONE HTML page. Then, create two separate print media CSS files: one for Firefox, the other for IE. Use a conditional comment to read the browser and figure which media print stylesheet to use.

A little bit of work, but it should work for you.